# How do I put this if statement into a function correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, variables

I am trying to put the if else code below into a function. The expected behavior is to return the arrays from the local scope to the global scope. Whenever I try and put the code below inside a function, I get a "code is not defined" reference error. I clearly need to return these arrays from the local scope to the global scope.

```
 if (randomnum == 1) {
      var codes = ["qjyreu", "achin", "eralnrde", "hiwel", "eW", "ni"];
      var words = ["jquery", "china", "learned", "while", "We", "in"];
      var finalAnswer = "Welearnedjquerywhileinchina";
    } else if (randomnum == 2) {
      var codes = ["oegs", "yob", "nignadc", "hTe", "ightn", "veery"];
      var words = ["goes", "boy", "dancing", "The", "night", "every"];
      var finalAnswer = "Theboygoesdancingeverynight";
    }
```

For reference, the randomnum is defined in the function rando:

```
function rando() {
  return (randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1);
}
rando();
```

Comment: And where is the error thrown at?

Comment: Lots  of logic missing here. What do you want with your arrays? What is the expected behaviour? Take a look at your if statement you are using randomnum that is never declared in your provided code block... If your console says codes is not defined you are calling a var that is not defined in this case your codes array i guess?

Comment: @RickBronger I am trying to return the arrays from the local scope to the global scope.

Comment: Edit your question, with a full explanation of what you want to achieve and were the problem is(I am trying to return the arrays from the local scope to the global scope). In this case your comment makes your question alot brighter

Comment: Okay, I edited it a bit. I am new here sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function rando() {
  var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  var finalAnswer
  if (randomnum == 1) {
      var codes = ["qjyreu", "achin", "eralnrde", "hiwel", "eW", "ni"];
      var words = ["jquery", "china", "learned", "while", "We", "in"];
      finalAnswer = "Welearnedjquerywhileinchina";
    } else if (randomnum == 2) {
      var codes = ["oegs", "yob", "nignadc", "hTe", "ightn", "veery"];
      var words = ["goes", "boy", "dancing", "The", "night", "every"];
      finalAnswer = "Theboygoesdancingeverynight";
    }
  return (finalAnswer);
}
rando();
```

The problem is you are using the statement in the return. So the other code will not executed. And also as you need to return something you have to define the final answer out of the `if` `else` statement. Then return it.

## Updated

If you want return all

```
function rando() {
  var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  var finalAnswer, codes, words;
  if (randomnum == 1) {
      codes = ["qjyreu", "achin", "eralnrde", "hiwel", "eW", "ni"];
      words = ["jquery", "china", "learned", "while", "We", "in"];
      finalAnswer = "Welearnedjquerywhileinchina";
    } else if (randomnum == 2) {
      codes = ["oegs", "yob", "nignadc", "hTe", "ightn", "veery"];
      words = ["goes", "boy", "dancing", "The", "night", "every"];
      finalAnswer = "Theboygoesdancingeverynight";
    }
  return ([finalAnswer, words, codes]);
}
rando();
```

Comment: So he declares lot of arrays and only returs a finalanswer that is in your code block missing a ; This isnt a good question so your answer isnt adding anything

Comment: The only expectations was to put the if else statement inside the function by the user. That's why I just gave this answer. Because the user clearly said the only need is to put the if else in the function

Comment: Hey, this was very helpful, but I am also trying to return var codes and var words. Can I also return codes and words along with finalAnswer?

Comment: I need to access the variable codes, words and final answer elsewhere in the document.

Comment: Whatever you want to return. Just declare it at the beginning of the function and then you can return it. If you declare a variable in the if else block that cannot be returned from our side of the block.

Comment: Now you see what happens. His question was not clear and complete. Stackoverflow is for other people with a similar question not asking the same question ;) 
Now we have a accepted answer that is answering a question that is not clear and complete ;) You can also see it in the vote of the questions

Comment: I just wanted to help. I updated my answer for all possible return. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: I understand(helping eachother is important!). Everybody with coding experience could have provided this answer. But normally people wait with answering until the question is clear. otherwise you get a massive comment section were the question is getting clarified